# How to specify content type when creating a list item using web services?

Tags: content-type, web-services, asp.net

This is what I have tried so far:

```
            string newPageXml = String.Format(@"<Batch OnError='Continue'>
                                    <Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>
                                        <Field Name='ID'>New</Field>
                                        <Field Name='ContentType'>MNC Site Page</Field>
                                        <Field Name='Title'>{0}</Field>
                                        <Field Name='BaseName'>{0}</Field>
                                        <Field Name='PublishingPageContent'>{1}</Field>
                                    </Method>
                                </Batch>", "Friday Memo for " + nextFriday.ToShortDateString(), newPageContent);

            xd = new XmlDocument();
            xd.LoadXml(newPageXml);
            newItem = xd.DocumentElement;
            createdItem = ceoList.UpdateListItems("Pages", newItem);
```

This code create an item in my list, but the item uses the default content type instead of the one I have specified in my XML.  Is there a way to do what I am trying above?

Answer (score 1):

I see this is a bit of an old question, but it is unanswered so I'll try to offer a possible solution...

You can try to add **ContentTypeId** field together with **ContentType**. Does it work now?